# Terraform extract account id from aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts

Tags: terraform

Given an account name, is it possible to extract the account id from

```
resource "aws_organizations_organization" "main" {
}
```

So something like:

```
output "account_id" {
  value = "aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts[name == 'account1']"
}
```

`account_id = 012345678901`

```
accounts = [
  {
    "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::012345678901:account/o-abc123/012345678901"
    "email" = "account1@email.com"
    "id" = "012345678901"
    "name" = "account1"
  },
  {
    "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::012345678902:account/o-abc123/012345678902"
    "email" = "account2@email.com"
    "id" = "012345678902"
    "name" = "account2"
  },
  {
    "arn" = "arn:aws:organizations::012345678903:account/o-abc123/012345678903"
    "email" = "account3@email.com"
    "id" = "320413348752"
    "name" = "account3"
  }
]
```

Comment: This post shows how to go about a list of maps. I think this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487972/iterate-over-list-of-list-of-maps-in-terraform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, I was able to solve with the following:

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "main" {}

locals {
  account-name = "account1"
  account-index = index(data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts[*].name, local.account-name)
  account-id = data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts[local.account-index].id
}

output "account_id" {
  value = local.account-id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you get version [2.21.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6842) or newer, you should be able to use the new `aws_organizations_organization` data source and filter it based on the account name. For example, though not tested:

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "org" {
  filter = {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["account1"]
  }
}
```

And then where you need the account id use `data.aws_organizations_organization.org.id`

Comment: ```Error: Unsupported block type

  on main.tf line 2, in data "aws_organizations_organization" "org":
   2:     filter {

Blocks of type "filter" are not expected here.```

Comment: @Christian I've edited the answer here to include the missing `=` sign that is needed for Terraform 0.12. Does that work as expected for you?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing and came across this. I'm having the same issue as @Christian. I looked it up in the docs and the filter property doesn't exist in the latest version (v3.37.0) of the AWS provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `null_data_source` for creating an email list. and then extract accounts using `matchkeys`.

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "main" {}

data "null_data_source" "main" {
  count = length(data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts)
  inputs = {
    emails = data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts[count.index]["email"]
  }
}

output "accounts" {
  value = matchkeys(data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts, data.null_data_source.main.*.outputs.emails, list("account1"))
}
```